# why android app that I develop get saved in internal memory?

Tags: android

Whenever I develop any android application, why it gets stored in internal memory. How to make application get installed on memory card (if available in phone)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This option is available with API versions >=8.**

[App Install Location Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html)

I dont know why you are desire to place it on external storage, but just remember that doesn't mean your data will stay there.

> The .apk file is saved on the external storage, but all private user data, databases, optimized .dex files, and extracted native code are saved on the internal device memory.

---

If you want to do it, in your manifest file specify:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    ... >
```

Comment: I have developed a simple calculator and I don't think it is storing any information anywhere. What do you think simple calculation application will be fine on memory card?

Comment: Also, by adding this "preferExternal" line in manifest. How logically the app will be install, first it looks for memory card and if there is no memory card then it gets installed on phone memory right ? or it can ONLY be installed on memory card by that code ?

Comment: IMHO, I think all apps should default to storage, I know it asserts if there is space, but i am unaware of anything else it checks.

Answer (score 2):

Add android:installLocation to your manifest.xml [install-location documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html)

Comment: And also, understand the consequences of doing it! when the sd card is unmounted or the phone is plugged as a mass storage device, the user won't be able to use your application.

Answer (score 2):

Add `android:installLocation="preferExternal"` to your `manifest` tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml`